# The next arrow hidden on the product images in fotorama zoom pages at magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6

I need to show the next arrow in all the pages of the product when the product page shown in full screen. Is there any option to enable next arrow in fotoram.js file? I have used magento 2.2.6 version.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue using css in gallery.less Next, Previous arrow hidden issue.

**Override  gallery.less file Copy gallery.less from magento/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less**

**And put in theme**

**File path: magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less**

**Add the below code in gallery.less file.**

```
.fotorama__arr.fotorama__arr--next,.fotorama__arr.fotorama__arr--prev
{
    display: block !important;
}
```

**After run below command:**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Let me know if any issue.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution. The solution is, to comment the following line in the `fotorama.js` file.

```
//$arrs.toggle(opts.arrows);
```

And add the following line below the comment.

```
if (opts.arrows) {
   $arrs.show();
}
```